# Retrieve current assembly or 'activation context' from Autofac

Tags: c#, .net, dependency-injection, autofac, .net-assembly

I have a service which loads a file from the base directory of an `Assembly`:

```
// pseudo
class FileLoaderService : IFileLoader {

    var _baseAssembly;

    .ctor(Assembly baseAssembly) {
        _baseAssembly = baseAssembly;
    }

    Stream LoadFile(string name) {
        return GetFileStream(_baseAssembly.Location + path);
    }
}
```

This service is being injected into various other resolved services located in different assemblies (some not known during compile time, but loaded at runtime). Now I'd like to provide the the current assembly (e.g. the assembly in which the resolved target type is located in) as a parameter when resolving `IFileLoader`.

I tried both, registering the `FileLoaderService` using a factory delegate as well as `ResolvedParameter`, however both only offer the current `IComponentContext`, which doesn't provide any information about the target type of the injection.

What I'm looking for is something along the lines of this:

```
containerBuilder.Register(context => {
    var targetType      = context.Target.TargetType; // does not exist
    var hostingAssembly = targetType.Assembly;
    return new FileLoaderService(hostingAssembly);
}).As<IFileLoader>();
```

I've seen a similar feature in other IoC containers such as Ninject (e.g. the current RequestContext offers a 'Target' property), so I hope this is possible in Autofac too. :)

### Usage example

```
// pseudo
class SomeTypeInAnotherAssembly

    .ctor(IFileLoader loader) {
        var fileStream = loader.LoadFile("test.png");
        // the file stream is now loaded from the base directory of AnotherAssembly.dll
        // since the injected IFileLoader was constructed using the assembly
        // of SomeTypeInAnotherAssembly
    }
```

Comment: `Target` in this case is the class where `IFolderLoader` is directly injected?

Comment: @YacoubMassad Exactly. Made an example to clarify. :)

Comment: Can you adapt the [log4net integration example](http://autofac.readthedocs.org/en/latest/examples/log4net.html) to suit your needs? Or maybe get some ideas from it?